# Deleting data in web.py

Tags: python, mysql, web.py

I'm following some of the recipes in the web.py cookbook after completing the tutorial. I am connected to my database all right, and can add items through web.py. However, I'm running into trouble when trying to delete items.

```
import web

db = web.database(dbn='mysql',user='root',pw='XXX',db='testdb')

render = web.template.render("templates/")

urls = (
'/','index',
'/add','add',
'/delete','delete',
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        todos = db.select('todo')
        return render.index(todos)

class add:
    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
        n = db.insert('todo',title=i.title)
        raise web.seeother('/')

class delete:
    def POST(self):
        db.delete('todo',where="id=1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls,globals())
    app.run()
```

When I go to the URL associated with the `"delete"` class, `web.py` returns `"none"`. I assume this is the number of rows that have been deleted (i.e., none) but why isn't the item with `id=1` being deleted?

[Here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/delete)'s the cookbook entry for deleting data

Comment: Do you have a column called id in your database?

Comment: You don't have a return statement in the POST function. Also please consider following RESTful principles and use the DELETE method for deletion, not POST.